# VSO vNext Multiple Builds,Different Build Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two build definitions in Visual Studio team Services.

I also have two release definitions in Visual Studio Team Services.

I want the release to be automatically triggered according to which build completes, but on the release definition.

When I go to the triggers tab, on the release definition, and select the continuous deployment option, it only gives me one artifact source label, for both builds.

How do I get my builds to produce different names artifact sources, so the releases can be triggered according to which build is run?

Answer (score 4):

OK, easy answer found

On the release definition, click on "Artifacts", then link to the second build definition, and then you can trigger the release from the second build.